# How to fix this error "-[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2834ca6f0"?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsobject, nscoding

I have an error when I try to encode my object. I've found lot of answers, but that didn't work for me :(

I cut my code, leaving only the important

This is main class "City" with tuple and Arrays of "cityHourlyForecast" and "cityDailyForecast" in it

```
class City: NSObject, NSCoding {    
    var name: String
    var currentWeather: (isDayTime: Bool, lastUpdate: Date?, temp_C: Int, temp_F: Int, weatherIcon: String, weatherText: String) =
        ( isDayTime: true,
          lastUpdate: nil,
          temp_C: 0,
          temp_F: 0,
          weatherIcon: "1",
          weatherText: "" )
    var hourlyForecast: Array<cityHourlyForecast> = []
    var dailyForecast: Array<cityDailyForecast> = []

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    // MARK: NSCoding

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(self.currentWeather, forKey: "currentWeather")
        coder.encode(self.hourlyForecast, forKey: "hourlyForecast")
        coder.encode(self.dailyForecast, forKey: "dailyForecast")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let name = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String
              else { return nil }
        self.init(name: name)
        if let currentWeather = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "currentWeather") {
            self.currentWeather = currentWeather as! (isDayTime: Bool, lastUpdate: Date?, temp_C: Int, temp_F: Int, weatherIcon: String, weatherText: String)
        }
        if let hourlyForecast = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "hourlyForecast") {
            self.hourlyForecast = hourlyForecast as! Array<cityHourlyForecast>
        }
        if let dailyForecast = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "dailyForecast") {
            self.dailyForecast = dailyForecast as! Array<cityDailyForecast>
        }
    }
}
```

cityHourlyForecast:

```
class cityHourlyForecast: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var dateTime: String
    var temp_C: Int

    init (dateTime: String, temp_C: Int) {
        self.dateTime = dateTime
        self.temp_C = temp_C
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(dateTime, forKey: "dateTime")
        coder.encode(temp_C, forKey: "temp_C")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let dateTime = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "dateTime") as? String,
              let temp_C = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "temp_C") as? Int
              else { return nil }
        self.init(dateTime: dateTime, temp_C: temp_C)
    }
}
```

cityDailyForecast:

```
class cityDailyForecast: NSObject, NSCoding {    
    var dateTime: String
    var temp_min_C: Int
    var temp_max_C: Int

    init (dateTime: String, temp_min_C: Int, temp_max_C: Int) {
        self.dateTime = dateTime
        self.temp_min_C = temp_min_C
        self.temp_max_C = temp_max_C
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(dateTime, forKey: "dateTime")
        coder.encode(temp_min_C, forKey: "temp_min_C")
        coder.encode(temp_max_C, forKey: "temp_max_C")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let dateTime = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "dateTime") as? String,
              let temp_min_C = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "temp_min_C") as? Int,
              let temp_max_C = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "temp_max_C") as? Int
              else { return nil }
        self.init(dateTime: dateTime, temp_min_C: temp_min_C, temp_max_C: temp_max_C)
    }    
}
```

And here I try to initialize array of "City" with getter and setter

```
var AccuCities:Array<City> {
    get{
        if let array = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Cities") as? Data {
            let decodedArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: array)
            return decodedArray as! Array<City>
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
    set{
        let encodedArray = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedArray, forKey: "Cities")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

What should I do to encode my array of "City" and save it to UserDefaults?

Comment: Any reason why you're using `NSCoding` instead of `Codable`?

Comment: I didn't know about `Codable`. All are advised to use `NSCoding`. I will study the subject of `Codable`. Thanks.

Comment: The issue here is in encoding `currentWeather`, which is a tuple. Your other property types get bridged into `NSCoding`-compliant objects (`Array` → `NSArray`, `String` → `NSString`), but this doesn't happen for tuples, which instead are bridged into an opaque `__SwiftValue` object, which doesn't conform to `NSCoding`. You'll need to encode each of the fields of the tuple separately in order to avoid this, or use an `NSCoding`-compliant object instead of a tuple to represent the weather. (FWIW, you'd run into the same issue with `Codable`, except it'd be at compile-time instead of runtime.)